# Any Recommendations For Disabling AccessResultCache on CD?

Tags: caching

I'm considering disabling AccessResultCache on our CD environment based on these instructions - https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/do-you-really-need-accessresultcache-on-cd-servers-if-no-then-disable-it-for-better-performance/. Has anyone done this, and are there any specifics to keep in mind?

I've tried finding documentation details on AccessResultCache's purpose or function but have only been able to find what is detailed in the link which specifies it's only necessary if authoring in the CD environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been a while since I dug into this, but if you're using Sitecore's security mechanisms to authenticate visitors to your public site (served by the CD environment), you'll want the AccessResultCache to improve the speed of that data access effort (querying .Net membership or however you may have extended it...). In this case, performance improvements can be observed by giving more capacity to that cache through a patch such as . . .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Caching.AccessResultCacheSize">
        <patch:attribute name="value" value="100MB"></patch:attribute>
      </setting>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

If you have a site that doesn't use Sitecore security, so all published content is visible to anyone who browses the proper URL on the Sitecore CD servers, then you may not need this cache. You may also want to look at disabling the security checks on the whole "web" database in such an example, as in . . .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <databases>
      <database id="web">
        <securityEnabled>false</securityEnabled>
      </database>
    </databases>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

You'll need to thoroughly test your implementation as people build *interesting* features into their projects sometimes, so take care with what I've recommended above. My notes are based on my anecdotal experiences and no promises they have relevance to you :) Have I sufficiently caveated that?

Comment: Yes, that's a great breakdown. I was concerned regarding authenticated visitors as we do have that feature in use.  The initial concern was due to the size of the AccessResultCache. It's substantially larger (twice) than any other caches, but it sounds like we will need that feature enabled. I appreciate the details.